# Equivalent of subprocess.Popen() in Ruby?

Tags: python, ruby

Is there an equivalent of subprocess.Popen() in Ruby? I have to run some programs in parallel and redirect their I/O. 
Something like

```
p = subprocess.Popen("python foo.py", stdin=inFile, stdout=outFile, stderr=outFile)
```

UPDATE: subprocess.Popen is a Python class that permits parallel execution of processes. The first argument is the statement to be executed. It could be a simple 'ls' command or a command to compile a C program. The stdin, stdout and stderr arguments take files as argument to redirect the input and output of a program you might run using it.

Comment: It will help if you explain what `subprocess.Popen()` does. Otherwise you artificially restrict the set of people able to answer your question to the intersection of people who are intimately familiar with process management in *both* [tag:ruby] and [tag:python].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Open3#popen3](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-popen3) will be useful.

Assuming you have a `test.rb` file as shown below:

```
v = gets.chomp
puts "#{v} @ #{Time.new}"
```

You could do:

```
require "open3"

stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr = Open3.popen3("ruby test.rb")

stdin.puts("hi")
puts stdout.gets(nil)
#=> hi @ 2016-02-05 19:18:52 +0530

stdin.close
stdout.close
stderr.close
```

---

For multiple sub-processes to execute in parallel, you can use threads as shown below:

```
require "open3"

t1 = Thread.new do |t|
  stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr1 = Open3.popen3("ruby test.rb")
  stdin.puts("Hi")
  puts stdout.gets(nil)
end

t2 = Thread.new do |t|
  stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr1 = Open3.popen3("ruby test.rb")
  stdin.puts("Hello")
  puts stdout.gets(nil)
end

t1.join
t2.join
```

Comment: 2 things. Can this run in parallel? That is can I run multiple Open3.popen3 instances in parallel without waiting for 1 to finish? Secondly, can I compile programs using this? Something like "gcc foo.cpp".

Comment: @Maruthgoyal  Not sure about parallel part.  Compilation should be fine

Comment: @Maruthgoyal You will have to use threads for parallel execution

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll give it a shot

Answer (score 0):

If you're not happy with other options, there's a ruby port of python's `Subprocess` library, open-sourced by Stripe.

https://github.com/stripe/subprocess

It has a `popen` function, e.g.

```
Subprocess.popen(
  ['python', 'foo.py'],
  stdin: inFile,
  stdout: outFile, 
  stderr: outFile)
```